# "duplicate row.names" error with corpus() in Quanteda

Tags: r, csv, quanteda

I've just upgraded my version of Quanteda and I'm getting an error I wasn't before.

```
spec_txt <- textfile("spec/Spectator_Texts_purged_R.csv", textField = "Cleaned.Text")
spec_corp <- corpus(spec_txt)
```

returns:

> Error in data.frame(texts = x, row.names = names(x), check.rows =
>   TRUE,  :    duplicate row.names: Spectator_Texts_purged_R.csv

I've searched for hanging commas in the CSV, and even cut the file down to three lines:

```
Issue,Signed,Text,Printer 
1,C,"This is test",A
2,R,"Test this is",B
```

And:

```
Text
"This is test"
"Test this is"
```

The error persists - am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I'd mistakenly upgraded quantedaData and *not* quanteda. Upgraded quanteda and the error is gone.

Comment: Good to know, sorry for the bug. For the future this sort of question/issue is better posted to https://github.com/kbenoit/quanteda/issues than to SO.

Comment: Cheers, Ken - to be honest I'm never sure when something is an bug or my own ignorance. I guess in this case it was a bit of both.